# how can I get a double number returned from a SOQL query through the rest API into a text field?

Tags: soql, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, outputtext

I have a SOQL query that pulls back 3 records with data from 5 fields into my NSDictionary. One of the fields in Salesforce is numeric (currency) and is returned in the query as a double. When I insert the value from the NSDictionary into the textlabel.text I don't have any success, i.e., no value is instered. Is my syntax incorrect at the point of insertion? Should I be converting it to text?

> cell.textLabel.text = [obj objectForKey: @"Sales_rev__c" ];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using `stringWithFormat` to do the type conversion?

```
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", [obj objectForKey: @"Sales_rev__c"]];
```

Comment: Thanks, I just tried that but the number value isn't returned, I just get 0.000000 returned instead (although on inspection at run time in the dictionary *obj there are two records that have a value greater than zero). I get the warning on the syntax: Format specifies type "double" but the argument has type "id".